# Unknown column 'DATE_START_SELECTED' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all rows from a table that lie between two dates. As a test, I set my two variables so that everything between 2000 and 2020 would show, but I ran into an error:

```
Unknown column 'DATE_START_SELECTED' in 'where clause'
```

This is the code I used:

```
$DATE_START_SELECTED = new DateTime('2000-01-01 05:59:00');
$DATE_END_SELECTED = new DateTime('2020-03-15 09:30:00');


$query = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE_START_SELECTED <= start_datetime AND end_datetime < DATE_END_SELECTED';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Any idea why? Thanks :)

Comment: Your $query literally contains %DATE_START_SELECTED% which is not valid...

Comment: Aha, I was unaware of that, I'm sorry - I will then update my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Object

```
$DATE_START_SELECTED = new DateTime('2000-01-01 05:59:00');
$DATE_END_SELECTED = new DateTime('2020-03-15 09:30:00');
```

The best bet is you have to convert it to string, like

```
$DATE_START_SELECTED = '2000-01-01 05:59:00';
$DATE_END_SELECTED = '2020-03-15 09:30:00';
```

Then, change the SQL to

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE 
start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
  AND 
end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
```

`DATE_START_SELECTED` is string,
in SQL mode will refer to column name, table name or database name

while `$DATE_START_SELECTED` is PHP variables

Comment: Thanks so much ajreal! In that case I can completely discard *new DateTime* and use the string code you have shown?